# Resonant Coupling for Optimal Power Transfer

Tags: inductor, wireless, resonance, wireless-charging, mutual-inductance

I am trying to read the following paper: 
[B. L. Cannon, J. F. Hoburg, D. D. Stancil and S. C. Goldstein, "Magnetic Resonant Coupling As a Potential Means for Wireless Power Transfer to Multiple Small Receivers," in IEEE Transactions on Power Electronics, vol. 24, no. 7, pp. 1819-1825, July 2009, doi: 10.1109/TPEL.2009.2017195.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eclaytronics/papers/cannon-tranpe09.pdf) 
and understand their design for a four coil power transfer.

The proposed system utilizes resonant coupling to wirelessly transfer power from a single source coil to multiple receiver coils. The experimental setup, as depicted in Fig. 1, involves a signal generator that supplies power to two LEDs through resonant coupling between large green coils and smaller black coils. Fig2 shows the schematic of their design.

[image]

In essence, my question is why can we just not use the first coil as both receiving power, and having resonance(make a two coil system, and not four coil system).

The paper in section VII briefly talks about why this might be the case, but unfortunately I do not understand their explanation. They refer to this,

[image]

And here is their explanation:

> The circuit model provides a simple way to understand what is accomplished by the resonant coupling mechanism and how it differs from simple inductive coupling. Fig. 4 shows three circuits providing inductive coupling to the load. Fig. 4(a) shows simple nonresonant coupling, while (b) and (c) shows variations of resonant coupling. In Fig. 4(b), the source and load resistances are approximately in parallel with parallel LC resonant circuits if the ohmic resistances R2 , R3 are small. Here the circuit Q is determined by the loading provided by RS , RL. In contrast, in Fig. 4(c), which corresponds to the system described in this paper, the source and load impedances are inductively coupled to the resonant circuits. In this case, the turns ratios can be chosen so that RS , RL are transformed into much larger effective resistances in parallel with the LC resonant circuits, resulting in a larger Q. Fig. 5 shows |(VL /VS )(ω)| as computed using these circuit models and component values appropriate for our experiment, as given in the Appendix. For the case of simple inductive coupling [Fig. 4(a)], the transfer function is almost constant at −58 dB for frequencies between 1 and 10 MHz, with low and high frequency 20 dB/decade roll-offs. For the values chosen, the Q of the circuit shown in Fig. 4(b) is relatively small, with only a weak resonant peak at a frequency that corresponds to ω0. In contrast, the impedance transformation provided by the coupling coils L1 , L4 for the circuit shown in Fig. 4(c) results in a much higher Q and coupling that is stronger by about 40 dB than the circuit shown in Fig. 4(b). Thus, the low Q and purely inductive systems have efficiencies many orders of magnitude lower than the high Q system.

It seems to me like the first coil is optimizing for "power transfer", and the second and third resonant coils are optimizing for "resonant frequency". Wouldn't the most optimal power transfer be at the resonant frequency, and using two coils instead of two would introduce unnecessary losses?  I dont really get which formulas necessarily would prove that the four coil setup is better compared to the two coil one.  I know that Q = (w_0*L)/R which leads me to think that more coils = more resistance and lower Q factor.

Edit: Here are the coupling coefficients provided by the paper:
k12 = 0.17 k13=0.0010, k14 = 0.021, k23 = 0.0047, k24 = 0.021 k34 = 0.76.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theory here, but I suspect the concepts used in the design of a Yagi-Uda antenna, with its unpowered resonating elements, might be related. I could be entirely off track though.

Comment: Do they mention the relative magnitudes of coupling factors? It sounds like k12 (primary to first resonator) should be strong, k23 (between resonators) very small (hence wireless power transfer, some distance is implied), and k34 large (other resonator to secondary).

Comment: The multi-coil design seems like a lot of faff to light a few LEDs. I can light LEDs a distance of16" above a 10" single-turn square coil and, the LEDs only have a tiny ferrite drum core as receiver. Hence, the trouble with the paper you linked is that they don't really try and compare against standard sort of technology and appears to go off at some obscure angle.

Comment: @TimWilliams they say that k12 = 0.17 k13=0.0010, k14 = 0.021, k23 = 0.0047, k24 = 0.021 k34 = 0.76. Does this mean that if we want to have resonance for power transfer between coils 2 and 3 because they are not coupled well? But why not just add resonance to the first and second coil also to further improve transmission in addition to the coupling.

Comment: @ELec - Your sentence, "Does this mean that if we want to have resonance for power transfer between coils 2 and 3 because they are not coupled well?" does not make sense. Redo?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I can see that coil 1 has a high resistance, which means that it will inherently not be able to have high Q factor. So we transmit all the energy from coil 1 to coil2, and make the coil 2 resonant with lower resistance which will allow for a higher Q factor?